# How to Multithread HttpWebRequests Efficiently?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, httpwebrequest

I am trying to multithread an httpwebrequest. It does not need to return a response, I just need to send them out as fast as possible. Currently I am using tasks but obviously that is not the most efficient way of doing things since that uses your system specs to determine threads rather than connection speed.

So I guess what I am trying to ask is what is the most effective way of using threads based on connection speed rather than the number of cores your PC has.

Thanks

Comment: Second @Asif's answer, asynchronous I/O will probably be more efficient than creating more threads in your case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `BeginGetResponse()` method which is an `async` method of `WebRequest`.

Answer (score 3):

By default, .Net application is allowed to open 2 connections to a web server. You can increase the number by setting this variable

```
//Set the connection limit of HTTP
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 20;
```

Either using regular calls or async method, with HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse, **you must properly dispose/close the Stream from GetReponseStream()**. By closing the Stream from GetResponseStream(), your application will terminate the HTTP connections after it finished.

For example, in the code below, I return StreamReader from the web

```
public static StreamReader LoadWeb(string URL)
    {
        if (!URL.StartsWith("http"))
        {
            URL = "http://" + URL;
        }

        HttpWebResponse myResponse = null;
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(URL));

        System.IO.Stream myStream = null;
        StreamReader myStreamReader = null;
        myRequest.Method = "GET";
        myRequest.Proxy = null;
        myRequest.Timeout = 60000;
        myRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        try
        {
            myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
            return null;
        }

        if (myResponse != null)
        {
            if (myResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                myStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
                myStreamReader = new StreamReader(myStream);
            }
        }

        return myStreamReader;

    }
```

After that, I got the return from the LoadWeb function

```
StreamReader reader = LoadWeb("http://www.google.com");
//...process the reader
//Finally, close the reader
if (reader != null)
     reader.Close(); //This line will terminate the HTTP connection
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The function is static. It can be used in multithreading environment. A better option is to use Task.Run() or async HttpWebRequest on higher .Net version.

Comment: Can't upvote this enough. Only 2 who thought that stupid limit up? Anyway thank you so much, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you build a queue of workers and keep track of running workers in a dictionary, launching new workers as running ones finish. This lets you adjust the number of active workers. It also gives you a collection of active workers in case you need to send them stop messages.

You'll need to add this to your app.config to get past the default connection limit of two:

```
<system.net>
<connectionManagement>
  <remove address="*"/>
  <add address="*" maxconnection="10" />
</connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

In the following example I use a callback to remove a worker from the queue and a `Monitor` to gate the emptying of the waiting worker queue.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static Queue<Worker> waitingWorkers = new Queue<Worker>();
        static Dictionary<int, Worker> activeWorkers = new Dictionary<int, Worker>();
        static int maxThreads = 10;
        static object waitLock = new object();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                waitingWorkers.Enqueue(new Worker(new WorkerDoneDelegate(WorkerDone)));
            }

            lock (waitLock)
            {
                while (waitingWorkers.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (activeWorkers.Count > maxThreads)
                    {
                        Monitor.Wait(waitLock);
                    }
                    Worker worker = waitingWorkers.Dequeue();
                    Thread thread = new Thread(worker.SendSomething);
                    thread.IsBackground = true;
                    activeWorkers[thread.ManagedThreadId] = worker;
                    thread.Start();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Queue empty");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void WorkerDone()
        {
            lock (waitLock)
            {
                activeWorkers.Remove(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Console.WriteLine("Worker done - id=" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
                Monitor.Pulse(waitLock);
            }
        }

        public delegate void WorkerDoneDelegate();
        public class Worker
        {
            static Random rnd = new Random();

            WorkerDoneDelegate Done;

            public Worker(WorkerDoneDelegate workerDoneArg)
            {
                Done = workerDoneArg;
            }

            public void SendSomething()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Worker send - id=" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
                Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(1, 1000));
                Done();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply use Parallel.For/ForEach it will do the thread optimization (choose pooling size, thread numbers, etc, etc..) for you :)